# HttpServletRequest.getParameter breaks Primefaces FileUploadFilter?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, servlet-filters

I have a problem with a custom filter which breaks the FileUploadFilter from Primefaces.

In the doFilter method of my custom filter I check for a query parameter:

```
String emailAddress = httpServletRequest.getParameter("emailAddress");
```

If I have this line the FileUploadFilter is not working. If I remove this line, everything works fine. I have no clue why. What am I missing? I tried HttpServletRequestWrapper with no difference, but as far as I know this is just to reuse the request body anyway?

Comment: what is the code depends on the result of this check? i think the bug there is in the conditional code not in this line.

Comment: See "Troubleshooting" section of the duplicate for the answer.